# Change the Highlight Color of selected text

Tags: flutter

When the user select a text from inside a TextField, the default highlight color is blue. How to change it to green for example ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 16):

## 2021 answer

Wrap with Theme and use copyWith to preserve other theme data.

```dart
 Theme(data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
   textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
     selectionColor: Colors.green)),
   child: TextFormField()
)
```

Comment: this only changes the color of the highlight, any idea how to change the color of text selectors as well?

Comment: @BhupeshVarshney if you are referring to the cursor in a textfield, its the cursorColor property. If you are using a custom theme, you can define the `textSelectionTheme` and use the `TextSelectionThemeData` to define cursorColor and highlighted color to your liking.

Comment: @BhupeshVarshney I left an answer to your issue below https://stackoverflow.com/a/76243684/1836024

Answer (score 8):

Wrap your text widget with theme and assign the color to the **textSelectionColor** property inside **ThemeData**

refer below code for same:- I have changed the text selection color to green

```
 Theme(
     data: ThemeData(textSelectionColor: Colors.green),
          child: TextField(
              controller: _inputController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Input"),
           ),
  ),
```

Comment: 'textSelectionColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use TextSelectionThemeData.selectionColor instead. This feature was deprecated after v1.23.0-4.0.pre

Answer (score 2):

change the value of `textSelectionColor` of your `ThemeData` and it will give you the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting all colors of the TextField and I also had the same problem. Since I wanted to change the color globally, what worked was setting the `primarySwatch` of the `MaterialApp`.

The nice thing is, that for the highlight color you don't have do deal with setting the alpha to some value so the selection is not as colorful as the rest. Setting the primary color does deal with having a lower intensity color for the selection and it looks good.

Unfortunately this approach does not work for individual TextFields.

The tint Color of my app can change. So I needed a way to convert the `Color` to a `MaterialColor` for which I wrote an extension. It is not perfect, because it misses the idea of different levels for different contexts. But it did not matter in my case. There is room for improvement. You could convert to `HSVColor` and set different `saturation` or `value`s on it, if you wanted to.

```
Color globalTint = <your color>;

return MaterialApp(
    title: 'YourAppTitle',
    theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: globalTint.toMaterialColor(),
        fontFamily: "YourFont",
        brightness: Brightness.light
    ),
    darkTheme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: globalTint.toMaterialColor(),
        fontFamily: "YourFont",
        brightness: Brightness.dark
    ),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: const Home()
);


extension ColorExtension on Color {

  MaterialColor toMaterialColor() {
    return MaterialColor(
      value,
      <Int, Color>{
        50:  this,
        100: this,
        200: this,
        300: this,
        400: this,
        500: this,
        600: this,
        700: this,
        800: this,
        900: this,
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please use this code.

```
Widget build(BuildContex contex){
  return MaterialApp{
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: kGreenColor,
          ),
          hoverColor: kPrimaryColor,
          indicatorColor: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].