# SelectableText.rich background color of selection, not of TextStyle

Tags: flutter, background-color, textselection

I'd like for the TextSpans in my SelectableText.rich to have the normal, blueish color when selected despite having a backgroundColor specified in their TextStyle. How can I do that ?

Here's some bad code for reproducibility :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: SelectableText.rich(TextSpan(children: [
          TextSpan(text: 'Some good old text for selection purposes',style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.grey),),
          TextSpan(text: 'The right background color')
        ]
      ))));
  }
}
```

And a screenshot of the behaviour I would like to prevent from happening :
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656386/change-the-highlight-color-of-selected-text

Answer (score 0):

You can add opacity to the TextSpan style color.

Example:

```
  TextSpan(
    text: 'texto',
    style: TextStyle(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.3),
    ),
  ),
```