# How to remove or disable text (substring) auto highlight in TextField or TextFormField. And the highlight substring pattern is unpredictable

Tags: flutter, textfield, textformfield

How to remove or disable text(substring) auto highlight in TextField or TextFormField. And the highlight substring pattern is unpredictable.
The input highlight color would affect text reading.

[image]

```
title: TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'search'.tr,
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.grey,
      fontSize: 18,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    ),
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
  style: TextStyle(
    color: AppThemes.primaryColorWine,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now, I don't think you can disable or remove the selection of text in `TextField` or `TextFormField`.

But you can change the color of the highlighted text & background if you don't like the color red.
If you want you can have transparent background for selected text to make it look like nothing has been selected. Customize the below code according to your way.

```dart
Theme(
   data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
         selectionColor: Colors.transparent),
      ),
   child: TextFormField(),
)
```

You can change the color of the cursor as well with the `cursorColor` property.

The above code has been taken from the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67204951/12555686

Comment: As a workaround, it could be considered.