# How to change cursor color in Flutter when text is selected?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried different searches to find the solution for how to change cursor's color when text is selected in Flutter, but ended up with no helpful answers. So,

**1.** how to change cursor's color in Flutter when text is selected?
**2.** Also, how to remove this bubble under cursor, that only appears when text is selected.

[image]

I have also looked up to Dart's API docs but couldn't find anything related.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656386/change-the-highlight-color-of-selected-text) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change cursor related properties using `TextSelectionTheme` in `ThemeData` as follwoing:

```
theme: ThemeData(
    fontFamily: 'Barlow-Regular',
    textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
      cursorColor: Colors.red,
      selectionColor: Colors.green,
      selectionHandleColor: Colors.green,
    ),
  ),
```